# Entity Framework is it possible using entity populated from a stored procedure but no physical table in database

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, mapping

I want to utilize the capability of EF to populate an entity from calling a stored procedure, but this entity does not need to map to a physical table, as it only exists in my application.

Is it achievable?

Many thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this article http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/30738a7c-5176-4333-aa83-98eab8548da5.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot! This article really answers my question. Complex type is exactly what I should to use instead of an empty fake table.